# Remove class, then hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$("body").removeClass("open", function()
{
    $(".sidebar").hide();
});
```

It removes the class from the `body`, but it doesn't hide the sidebar and I'm not sure why. The class names are definitely correct.

I need the sidebar to be hidden after the animation of removing class `.open` is done.

Comment: .removeClass() doesn't accept a callback function. Read the docs.

Comment: Is it important that your events occur sequentially? (They will anyway, but why are you forcing it?)

Answer (score 3):

`removeClass` only takes one argument; It's immediate, not asynchronous, so you can just run this.

```
$("body").removeClass("open");
$(".sidebar").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you passing a callback to `removeClass`? It doesn’t accept one.

```
$("body").removeClass("open");
$(".sidebar").hide();
```